# QTP 10 crashes on clicking on open test from Open menu

Tags: qtp

I am using QTP 10 on Windows XP, since last 2 days, when I open a test, QTP stops working. It crashes.

Comment: Did you manage to validate the suggestions that came up? I am curious to learn what´s the cause in your case.

Comment: I was running it in VMware. So had to reinstall VMware and QTP both. Now it is working.

Comment: Make That an answer, and accept it. Please.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

### Corrupted QTP Installation

During script execution, there are cases when something unexpected happens and the script is unable to recover. QTP hangs. The tendency for most folks is to kill the process via the task manager. This could corrupt QTP. It may load successfully, but certain functions can behave abnormally.

Consider checking also if any new software was recently installed in your machine, which could have affected QTP.

### **Hard Drive Full**

Speaking from experience, I faced this kind of situation when the drive partition that QTP was installed in was already full. Check your disk space.

### Text Recognition Feature

Apparently, there's a driver called **pal_drv.sys** that can cause QTP to hang. It can be removed by navigating to `/QTP-Install-Path/bin` and running:

```
nt_tr.exe –remove
```

Comment: Hello Jops, I did run this command in cmd, and message came that 'Test recognition has been installed successfully'. I then reboot my machine, but still tyhere is the same problem.

Comment: Can I delete 'pal_drv.sys' file manually by going to the bin folder?

Comment: Manually deleting anything from the installation direction could have potential consequences, so it's not recommended. Why does it say "installed", it should have been "uninstalled" right?

Comment: Ya it should be uninstalled, but it shows installed. I tried it again now, but in vain

Comment: Create a copy of pal_drv.sys then go delete it, and try. Just restore it if still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it does not crash -- **the open dialog is active, but not visible** because it is outside of the visible area. QTP stops responding since the open dialog is application-modal.

**Push Alt-Backspace, this pops up the window´s system menu. Select "move", and move the window until you see it.**

This happens if you change your dual display configuration, or switch from dual to single display config when the open test dialog was positioned on the secondary screen the last time QTP was used.

This at least is the #1 newbie problem I observe in the projects I work in. I am pretty sure that this is what is happening.

Comment: Actually as soon as I click on open menu-> tests, a window pops up saying "We have encountered a problem. Qtp needs to be closed". So when I click on OK (There is only 1 button), QTP exits completely.

Comment: Well then that´s a case for HP support. Or completely de- and re-install QTP.

Comment: I did uninstal and re-installed it, but now QTP doesnt open only. The same error message appears again.

Comment: Did you do a *clean* uninstall, i.e. uninstall, then delete all related registry keys under HKLM and HKCU, and delete all files under program files?